# cellForRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue return different label colors

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicolor

I have a custom table view cell. Inside the cell is a label I added from the object library and I gave it a `viewWithTag` value of 1. The label in the table view cell has a yellow background color. Here's the code:

Within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have

```
let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
label.backgroundColor = yellowColor // yellowColor is a regular UIColor I defined elsewhere
println(label.backgroundColor) // returns Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.980392 0.776471 0 1)
```

Now, within `prepareForSegue` I have

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!)
let labelBackgroundColor = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel).backgroundColor
println(labelBackgroundColor) // returns Optional(UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0)
```

Therefore I'm getting `Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.980392 0.776471 0 1)` and `Optional(UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0)` from the same label's backgroundColor property according to my understanding. Shouldn't it be the same RGB value? What am I missing here? If this is the wrong way to access the label's backgroundColor property, how would I go about accessing it properly?

Comment: Do all your rows have the same label background color? Is `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` returning the correct indexPath?

Comment: The correct indexPath is being selected because I've used println() for things like the label's text and it prints the proper string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to the color change that happens on selection. If you set the selection style to "none" for your cell, the correct color is reported in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar, this worked. Do you know why default selection changes the color value by chance?

Comment: @Aaron When you select the cell, you get a color change, but I'm not sure what views or layers get changed. Apparently, the background color is changed to black.